# unable to remove linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic

Tags: 16.04, kernel

I am trying to install the latest kernel, but when I run

```
sudo apt-get -f install linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic
```

I get this error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0-78.99).
linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic set to manually installed.
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0-78.99).
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic set to manually installed.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 76 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 153 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 193286 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic (4.4.0-71.92) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-71-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-71-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-71-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_dPzLCV/lib/modules/4.4.0-71-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_dPzLCV/lib/modules/4.4.0-71-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

And it seems to get stuck indefinitely...could anyone tell me how I can debug this, or recover from it?

Thanks.

edit: /boot isn't full, its got 254Mb free space

edit2: the problem seems to be with **update-initramfs**, when I run `sudo update-initramfs -u` its stuck indefinitely

Comment: Why are you installing kernels this way instead of the normal way? And why do you have 76 packages not upgraded?

Comment: Hiya, I've checked /boot and its got 41% free space (254Mb). There are 76 packages not upgraded, because I'm unable to do 'apt-get upgrade'...unattended-upgrades got stuck at this step (removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71') and I've been trying to fix it ever since :(

Comment: You could try using `aptitude`, its problem resolution capability is pretty darn good.  Just `sudo aptitude` then press `u` to update.  It will list suggestions for problems it finds at the bottom in red.  You can step through all the suggestions or apply one by pressing the appropriate key listed at the bottom.  It cannot fix everything but it's pretty good.